# How to Add REGION in Visual Studio in aspx Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I use asp.net with code behind and c#.

So I have two file for every .aspx page in VS 2010.

In .aspx.cs page I am able to add regions in my code using:

```
#region Name Region
#endregion
```

My questions:

- How to do it in file .aspx? #region seems working only in .cs file.
- Do you know any other useful tag to help me to organize better my code both for .aspx and .cs file?
- Do you know the keyboard shortcuts to expand or collapse all my region in my code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do you know the keyboard shortcuts to expand or collapse all my region in my code?

Here are some key chords for you.

<kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> will collapse all the regions in the opened document (or the highlighted section).

<kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> will collapse or open the collapsible section the cursor is on.

<kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> will collapse or open everything.

Now here is one i use frequently, especially in javascript files: highlight some code, then press <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> to hide it, which will produce a little expander `+-` next to the collapsed code. Press <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> to expand it again.

Also see [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx) by Scott Guthrie which details some posters you can download with lots of the VS shortcut key combinations on them.

Comment: In my opinion, this does not fully answer the question, because the given solution cannot fully replace the features of `region` and `endregion`. The item collapsing of ASPX items with be expanded by default while regions would not.

Comment: @modiX This is an old question, and everyone acknowledges that there is no absolute solution, so all the answers suggest something that will get as close as possible to what the OP wants. Leaving a comment 4 years after the fact saying *"in my opinion this doesn't solve the issue fully"* is not helpful at all. If you have a solution (hint: there isn't one) then by all means leave an answer. BTW VS now remembers the collapse state of regions, so your comment is not fully correct.

Answer (score 4):

The editor of Visual studio for aspx files already provide features like collapsing and expanding for individual elements of HTML.

You can hit '-' at the left most corner in the editor to collapse the corresponding HTML tag (Div or table, etc.) and sub contents.

Comment: what if the OP legitimately wants to hide some nasty script code?

Comment: When opening the document, this will show the code again, while regions would hide it initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting it inside a some other container. For example

<asp:Literal id="JavaScriptRegion" runat="server">

.... I put all my javascripts here.

</asp:Literal>

So I can collapse the Javasript "region".
If it's inside your body section and you have asp ctrols inside you might try something like

<div style="">....

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that if you use the hotkeys:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

etc., they wont be saved when you save and reopen your project.