# Collapsible areas in front-end?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a lot of front-end code that would be more readable if I could use collapsible areas like #region in C#. Is there a way to do that in the front-end?

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Add REGION in Visual Studio in aspx Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242879/how-to-add-region-in-visual-studio-in-aspx-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, I'll refer you to this post: [How to Add REGION in Visual Studio in aspx Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242879/how-to-add-region-in-visual-studio-in-aspx-files). Observe the answer for some simple tips; though, Visual Studio already provides the ability to collapse html elements (by default) in the editor gutter.  If you are referring to JavaScript (your question is vague), then I would refer you to this plugin: [JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed?SRC=VSIDE)